# Set background with custom shape and a png image

Tags: android, view, background, drawable

I have a `view` to which I want to set a `drawable` image which is very easy. the images is set properly but the corners are square. If I try to make the corners rounded by using `shape` `attribute` in an `xml drawable` then the corners are round but I cannot find a way to set the image `background` as the background attribute of the `view` is used to set the xml `drawable` for corner.

Is there a way to have the `background` as an image as well as rounded corners. I am aware of solutions like using an image with rounded corners but I don't want to bother the graphics team for such smaller issues and I want to have a generic solution.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `dispatchDraw` method of your view(or `onDraw` in case it's not a view hierarchy)

```
private final Path mClipPath;
.......
mClipPath = new Path();
mClipPath.addRoundRect(new RectF(x,y,z,t),radius,radius,Direction.CW);
........
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(final Canvas canvas){
    canvas.clipPath(mClipPath); // clip the canvas so that we can draw only in the boundaries specified by mClipPath
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas); //now draw the view on the clipped canvas
    .....  //do other drawing
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response..
yes, it works. But I was just wondering if there is a way to set the custom shape along with a bg background, rather than creating a custom View. anyways it solved my problem.